# "Unknown error occurred" when setting custom policy for Interface VPC Endpoint for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-private-link

I'm trying to allow AWS Lambda residing in a private VPC to invoke another Lambda not in any VPC. I'm purposely avoiding use of NAT gateways in favor of Interface VPC Endpoints as they're a bit cheaper to use. However, I'm running into trouble configuring a custom policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "[~some stuff~]",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:[~region~]:[~taken out~]:function:Test-Invoked"
    }
  ]
}
```

This was generated by the policy generator provided by AWS, which I copied and pasted. When I tried to create the endpoint, this got overwritten by the default All access. After I tried to change this once the endpoint was created, AWS takes me to an error page saying "Error: An unknown error occurred".

Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface endpoint policy is **invalid**. Its missing [Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-access.html) element for once.

But my advise would be to use **default policy**, and control access to the endpoint using security groups, and to control permissions to invoke the second lambda by means of IAM roles and/or lambda's resource-based permissions.